# Can we limit the value of a z3 real term by its numerator/denominator representation?

Tags: z3

In z3, a real term's value is represented by the division of two integer numbers: numerator and denominator. I very often find real values (as solutions to my z3 problems) with very large numerators and denominators like as follows:

29176049827299110215982818410792217459/804618286561124267999713087296957062500
-556895298158182412321541102649719164259083/4272120792496289300944476637003193523343750

There are often other assignments of those real variables in the case of alternative solutions (to the same problem) with smaller numerators and denominators. I am just wondering whether I can limit the numerator and denominator (e.g., with respect to the number of digits). Actually, I am looking for a z3 feature for this purpose. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: There isn't any facility for bounded complexity models in Z3. It is an interesting point, but we don't have a way to control search for models with small numeric representations.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am just wondering whether you like to add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true in general that a real number in Z3 is represented as a ratio of a numerator and a denominator.  This would restrict Z3 to rationals.  For an example where Z3 returns an irrational number, try:

```
(declare-const x Real)
(assert (= (* x x) 2.0))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

That being said, for many specific problems, Z3 will indeed respond with a rational representation of a real number.  I think this often happens when it's possible for your problem to be re-normalized and solved in the integers.  In these situations, you could try to *force* your problem to be solved in the rationals using techniques similar to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120447/does-z3-support-rational-arithmetic-for-its-input-constraints). Then, you can assert that your number has a numerator `p < p_max` for some constant `p_max`.

Comment: Two more comments: (1) If you add cosmetic restrictions to your model, especially mixing real and integer arithmetic, you might cause Z3 to fail.  (2) you could instead start your .smt2 file with `(set-option :pp.decimal true)` if you just want a more reasonable looking result and are OK with a decimal approximation.