# Does z3 support rational arithmetic for its input constraints?

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

In fact, does the SMT-LIB standard have a rational (not just real) sort? Going by its [website](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories.shtml), it does not.
If x is a rational and we have a constraint x^2 = 2, then we should get back ``unsatisfiable''. The closest I could get to encoding that constraint is the following:

```
;;(set-logic QF_NRA) ;; intentionally commented out  
(declare-const x Real)  
(assert (= (* x x) 2.0))  
(check-sat)  
(get-model)
```

for which z3 returns a solution, as there is a solution (irrational) in the reals. I do understand that z3 has its own rational library, which it uses, for instance, when solving QF_LRA constraints using an adaptation of the Simplex algorithm. On a related note, is there an SMT solver that supports rationals at the input level?

Comment: SMT-LIB does not have rational types. You can emulate rationals by using two integers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure it's possible to define a Rational sort using two integers as suggested by Nikolaj -- I would be interested to see that.  It might be easier to just use the Real sort, and any time you want a rational, assert that it's equal to the ratio of two Ints.  For example:

```
(set-option :pp.decimal true)
(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const p Int)
(declare-const q Int)
(assert (> q 0))
(assert (= x (/ p q)))
(assert (= x 0.5))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x p q))
```

This quickly comes back with

```
sat
((x 0.5)
 (p 1)
 (q 2))
```

Comment: Trying this on 4.8.7, I find that I have to `(assert (= (* x q) p)` for it to be satisfiable.